# GenericObjectPoolConfig missing maxActive maxWait and whenExhaustedAction missing from common pools 2.X

Tags: java, apache-commons

I need to migrate a project from apache.common.pools 1.x to 2.x but I'm having some troubles with the class GenericObjectPoolConfig because I cannot find the parameter maxActive, maxWait and whenExhaustedAction. These parameters were present in 1.x but in this version I cannot find something similar. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html). Basically `maxActive` is now `maxTotal`.